# DOORS requirement partition not shown

Tags: export, partition, ibm-doors

I'm using;
DOORS client 9.6.1.0 and DOORS server 9.2.0.0.

The problem; An export of a partition file I made last week is no longer shown in the Exported Partitions view on my DOORS client. Therefore I cant synchronise or rejoin it.

I'm wondering if there is a problem using the slightly older server with the newer DOORS client, although the IBM help says it should be compatible.

Does anyone have a workaround?

Kind Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. 
It was because the partition contents were read only. Therefore no change is possible on the partition, so no synchronization with the partition would be necessary, so the DOORS client didn't show the partition.